# Send user in server a message by User ID

Tags: javascript, node.js, discord.js

I want to use Discord.js to send a message to a User based on their User ID. So not whenever a user sends a message, but whenever I want.

Example code:

```
bot.fetchUser("123456").then((user) => {
    user.send("Test");
});
```

Where `123456` is the Discord User ID.

This returns a `401 unauthorized` error.

Comment: Are you sure that the user shares at least a guild with the bot? Does this happen with every user or just some of them?

Comment: @FedericoGrandi It does share a guild (same server), and happens to every single one

Comment: Does [this issue](https://github.com/discordjs/discord.js/issues/683) describe your problem or it's something different?

Comment: @FedericoGrandi It kinda does. It's not exactly the same function and all. But yeah

Comment: Try installing discord.js from the GitHub branch mentioned in that issue: `npm i --save discordjs/discord.js#v8`

Answer (score 0):

```
var user = message.guild.members.get("123456");
user.send("Test");
```

I've not tested this. I'm sure this is working, but I'm a human. Place a command when I made a mistake!